# How do I minimize exchange rate spread costs when shopping online?

Tags: currency, eur-euro, usd-us-dollar, spreads

I get my income in euros. I need to pay for stuff in USD because I use shops like Dealextreme where the base currency is USD. I have a Visa Debit card (so not a real Visa) since I am a student but have stable income streams monthly. I get the following spread-costs with my card:

- Dealextreme, 9.59%, when paying in euros - the payment is in euros and the base currency is USD [1]
- Dealextreme, 2.06%, when paying in USD - the payment and the base currency are both USD [2]

I get the current course of one euro in USD from Google.

The spread-cost, 2.06%, is huge. I would like to get it even smaller.
**Which credit-card minimizes the given spread-cost even more?**

**2. Is there any other ways to minimize the given spread-cost even more?**

I did not use Paypal in buying my merchandise. I am not sure about Paypal's spread-cost, but it's probably worse than paying directly with the given credit card.

**Appendix**

```
[1]
>>> 24.10/18.74                  
1.2860192102454644
>>> de = 24.10/18.74                # one euro in USD when paying with euros
>>> right = 1.4155
>>> diff = right - de
>>> ave = (right + de)/2
>>> diff / ave
0.09585775978455527

[2] 
>>> 24.10/17.38
1.3866513233601843
>>> de = 24.10/17.38                     # one euro in USD when paying with dollars
>>> right = 1.4155
>>> diff = right - de
>>> ave = (right + de)/2
>>> diff / ave
0.020590377399905716
```

Comment: Have you looked into doing the currency transfer outside of the credit card transaction? Perhaps if you opened up a bank account intended for international use you would be able to move money into USD and spend it in USD.

Comment: @duffbeer703 Thank you for your point! I knew that there is a more efficient way to do the thing. Need to find out now the most efficient bank account for the given purpose.

Comment: @duffbeer703 I opened a new thread about an international bank account which has only USD for a student: http://money.stackexchange.com/questions/11824/international-bank-account-only-for-usd-for-student, to minimize spread-costs in online shopping.

Comment: Is there a way for you to get income in USD?

Comment: Not at the moment, but in the future yes. Yes, the best way to avoid the currency exchange costs would be to avoid the currency exchanges.

Comment: I live in Canada. My discount brokerage charges me a spread of only about 1.5% each way for CADUSD and USDCAD. The large international discount broker [Interactive Brokers](http://enwp.org/Interactive_Brokers) charges even less for foreign-exchange transactions (though they do charge a monthly fee to inactive traders). Do you have some investments, such as mutual funds? Is your net worth high enough that it's worth opening a brokerage account to hold your investments? (Note that many brokerages charge all sorts of fees to customers with small accounts.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply, pay in the same currency as registered in the market - normally the native currency is the cheapest and options are with 2.5% spread cost.
If you cannot do it, simply pay the standard 2.5% spread cost directly to your bank or to the shop if possible.

Comment: +0. The answer was impossible for me to understand. Dear readers: please [edit] the answer so that it is more grammatically correct and so more understandable. Dear Masi: Please [edit] your answer to include both a full answer in English and a full answer in your native language. This will help us fix the English version.

Comment: Edited. Simpler better. Not any magic science there. I do not cover those little details here because every person is individual and needs special care and planning depending on many factors like country of residence, age and so on.