# International Bank Account Only For USD For Student

Tags: spreads, germany, sweden, finland

*I am not sure whether I use the right terminology in the heading, since I call the bank account which has only USD "international bank account" because it is not in euros.* I need only USD for online shopping.

I need only USD in the international bank account currently to [decrease the spread-costs in online shopping](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/11821/to-minimize-spread-costs-in-shopping-online).

The prices of international bank accounts are expensive in Nordic countries: 1.5% to put money there and 1.5% again to consume the given money in the biggest Nordic bank, [Nordea](http://www.nordea.fi/Henkil%C3%B6asiakkaat/P%C3%A4ivitt%C3%A4iset+raha-asiat/Valuuttatili/Hinnat+ja+korot/873552.html). So no benefit of using international bank accounts of Nordea only for USD transactions.

Assume that I am not going to travel to USA in four years.

**1. Is there any bank account in USA that I can open without visiting USA?**

**2. What is the cheapest international bank account for me in Europe?** I am ready to travel to Germany for instance, since it is so close to me.

Answer (score 3):

If you only need to buy stuff online you could consider using paypal perhaps?

If you really need an bank account, you could also look at an offshore bank account, [HSBC](http://www.expat.hsbc.com/1/2/hsbc-expat/ways-to-bank-with-us/banking-in-multiple-currencies) has accounts in multiple currencies, but you will need to be eligible (have a ton of money and provide some documentation).